# Multipage synchronous two column abstract in a two column article

Tags: two-column, multicol, paracol

I want to get article with two column abstract, spanning to the second page synchronously. The idea is to show original and translated abstracts. I use `papacol` package for this.
The main body should also use two columns, and here is a problem.

1. `\twocolumn` command makes unwanted new page.
   `\let\clearpage\relax \twocolumn` results in overlapped text.
   The result is:

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

2. It is possible to place the whole article body in `multicols` environment,
   but I would not like it because of the floats usage. Here is the screen of the second page (without a figure) to show the desired view:

[image: 1]

What is the way to get the page like in the second example, but without `multicol` ?

**UPDATE #1**

Is it possible to use `paracol` to get classical left-to-right text flow in columns ?

---

Minimal example code:

```
 
\documentclass[english,twocolumn]{paper}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Example article with two column abstract}

\author{Author A.R.}

\onecolumn

\maketitle

\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm

\begin{abstract}

\begin{paracol}{2}        
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \switchcolumn    
    \textit{\lipsum[1-4]}
\end{paracol}


\end{abstract}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm

{
\let\clearpage\relax 
\twocolumn
}
\textbf{The dobule line above should split the abstract from the article body.}


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}

\lipsum[5-7]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\tcbox[colback=green!30, colframe=blue!30!black]{\begin{tabular}{cc}A & B \\ C & d\end{tabular}}
\caption{Simulation results for the network.}
\label{fig_01}
\end{figure}

\section*{Acknowledgment}

The authors would like to thank...


\end{document}
```